# ASP.NET MVC4 Custom Exception Handling C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, exception

I am trying to create a custom error page to handle errors thrown when validating a registration form. I am using C# ASP.NET MVC 4.  I have attempted this in a number of ways, all ultimately coming to various errors.  Using the standard error, the system works properly, however it does not work with custom errors.

When attempting to simply do `<customErrors mode="on" />` I get this error.

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed.

When attempting to use `<customErrors mode="on" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml" />`
Or using a custom controller as well `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error' />` I receive this error

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

**Here is the appropriate code from the controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Confirm(User data)
        {
            Boolean error = false;
            User newUser = new User(data);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (User u in _users)
                {
                    if (newUser.email.Equals(u.email))
                    {
                        error = true;
                    }
                }
                if (error == true)
                {
                    throw new Exception("That email already exists!");
                }
                _users.Add(newUser);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid data entry, please try again.");
            }
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Countdown");
        }
```

**Errors.cshtml (Error controller returns a similar view)**

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img src="http://i1382.photobucket.com/albums/ah259/rogha189/running-stopwatch-1_zps95faa3c7.jpg" "></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">
                <h3>An Error has occurred.</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        <p>@Model.Exception.Message</p>
                    }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Any chance that " Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. "? Have you tried to debug? Have you tried to set page that can't fail (i.e. no usage of `Model` at all or at leas all necessary null checks)?

Comment: How does your Error controller looks like? Is it correctly building the `HandleErrorInfo` model and passing it to the view?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the 'Runtime Error' for the null value of the *Model.Exception* in the 'Errors.cshtml' page. Along with *Model* check null value for *Model.Exception* before using it.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to log the exception anywhere or your purpose is just to redirect to error page and show some custom message ?